# lxml removes spaces and line breaks in <head>

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, lxml

This small program:

```
from lxml.html import tostring, fromstring
e = fromstring('''
<html><head>
        <link href="/comments.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </body>
</html>''')

print (tostring(e, encoding=str)) #unicode on python 2
```

will print:

```
<html><head><link href="/comments.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link
href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </body></html>
```

The spaces and line breaks in head removed.
This happens even if we place the two <link> elements in <body>.
It seems blank text nodes (\s*) between head elements are removed.

How I can preserve spaces and line breaks between <link>s? (I expect output to be exactly same as input)

Comment: lxml is for parsing and creating XML and HTML. What is outputted is guaranteed to have the correct syntax and be parseable with other tools, etc. There is no guarantee that it will preserve the formatting, as that is not the aim of lxml. If you want to modify your HTML while preserving the formatting of the HTML (why would you want that?) then lxml is the wrong tool.

Comment: Although you could possibly use a different parser or tokenizer. But it's not going to be worth the effort. Explain why you need to preserve whitespace instead. Normally you don't.

Comment: The input is given by user and I use lxml to check and clean the syntax. I want to give the same input to user if input has no errors.

Comment: So if it has no errors, return the original? :-) You might want to look into htmltidy or other tools that already does this. I *believe* BeautifulSoup will preserve whitespace, but Python 3 support is not very good yet.

Comment: BeautifulSoup (3.1.0.1, latest version compatible with python 3) doesn't preserves whitespaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used html5lib to parse html and generate lxml like tree with it.

`parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=html5lib.getTreeBuilder("lxml"), namespaceHTMLElements=False)`

Comment: UPDATE: This is now fixed (using lxml 3.4.2)

Answer (score 2):

for me

`print (tostring(e, encoding=str))`

returns

```
>>> print (tostring(e, encoding=str))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 1493, in tostring
    encoding=encoding)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2836, in lxml.etree.tostring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:53416)
TypeError: descriptor 'upper' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

I cannot speak to the descrepencey, but I do suggest setting the argument `pretty_print` to true

```
>>> etree.tostring(e, pretty_print=True)
'<html>\n  <head>\n    <link href="/comments.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n    <link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n        <span/>\n        <span/>\n    </body>\n</html>\n'
```

you will need to import etree `from lxml import etree`

when outputted to an outfile the spaces and newlines will be perserved. Also with `print`

```
>>> print(etree.tostring(e, pretty_print=True))
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/comments.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
        <span/>
        <span/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am sure you have checked out the [API](http://lxml.de/api/index.html), but incase you haven't here is information on [tostring()](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring).
It is also safe to assume you have seen the [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) on the lxml website. I would love to see some more 'good' resources. I am new to [lxml](http://lxml.de/) myself and anything new and *good* to read would be welcomed.

**Updated**

you said you wouldconsider `sed` if you could not find a good python solution.

this should accomplish it with `sed`

`sed -i '1,2d;' input.html; sed -i '1 i\<html><head>' input.html`

this is running two `sed` procedures. the first deletes the first 2 lines. the second inserts `<html><head>` on the first line.

**UPDATE #2**

I should have thought about this more. you can do this with python

```
    >>> import re
    >>> newString = re.sub('\n  ', '', etree.tostring(e,encoding=unicode,pretty_print=True), count=1)
    >>> print(newString)
      <html><head>
            <link href="/comments.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
         </head>
         <body>
           <span/>
           <span/>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I use python 3, with python 2 use `unicode` instead. Also i guess this exception is because of old version of lxml. it seems you install lxml from package manager and not with easy_install.

Comment: pretty_print rearrange elements! I want to preserve spaces, but not prettify. In fact I want get input from user and not change it with from_string and then to_string.

Comment: ah, python3 might explain the small disagreements in syntax. I still recommend `pretty_print=True`, from my output it does what your question asked preserves spaces and line breaks. Perhaps update your question using `pretty_print=True`, its output, and contrast it against your desired output.  Because, I am not quite sure what your asking now. NOTE, do this using `etree.tostring`

Comment: See edited version of question. I expect output to be exactly same as input. pretty_print=True adds a \n between <html> and <head>.

Comment: true, there is no 'easy' way to do this. Is it necessary? Its not impossible, but I dont see it happening using tostring() and a lot of uncessary code. would you consider post-processing the outfile. this would be easy with `sed`

Comment: That will not actually preserve formatting, it will just recreate something that looks like what this example has...

Comment: @Lennart, would you care to explain further? Like I have mentioned, I am a new comer to lxml myself and would not mind being proven wrong, however, I fail to see what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: @matchew: Your answer does not preserve whitespace. It *adds* whitespace. If the whitespace in the example changes, your example will not change with it.

Comment: as Lennart Regebro says, I don't need a specific code to check this specific example!! There are many more examples that lxml changes the whitespaces. I'm going to change the cpython code of lxml, (if have enough time!)